# Join two different table having common row using PIG

Tags: join, apache-pig

Suppose I have two datasets . 
**DS1:**
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5

**DS2:**
1 pass
2 fail
3 pass
4 pass
5 fail

and i want to get a output like :
a 1 pass
b 2 fail
c 3 pass
d 4 pass
e 5 fail

now my question is,what   **pig**command should i use to get the desire output?

Answer (score 0):

[JOIN](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28inner%29).Assuming the data in the files are tab delimited.

```
A = LOAD 'ds1' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (a1:charrarray,a2:int);
B = LOAD 'ds2' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (b1:int,a2:chararray);
C = JOIN A BY a2, B BY b1;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE C.$0,C.$1,B.$1;
DUMP D;
```